# Non contradiction principle

Tags: logic, axioms, formal-proofs

I want to know where do come exactly the contradiction principle and if a formal proof system needs it to work.
Have you some books references who talks about it ?

Comment: See [Contradiction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/contradiction/). It was firstly expressed in logic by [Aristotle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-noncontradiction/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motive for $p\land\neg p$ not being true is that,

1. *if* from $p\land\neg p$ you can deduce $(p\lor q)\land\neg p$, and
2. *if* from $(p\lor q)\land\neg p$ you can in turn deduce $q$,

[you can prove anything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion). This phenomenon, called "explosion", makes for a logic that is neither useful nor interesting.

A logic in which a contradiction *doesn't* lead to explosion is called [paraconsistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic) or Brazilian, and requires the rules of inference to be weakened enough that at least one of the above steps is invalid.